# How to scale polygon using shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

Im trying to scale one shape to a larger one, like this:
[image]

I have an example here

```
poly_context = {'type': 'MULTIPOLYGON',
'coordinates': [[[[1, 2], [2, 1], [4, 3], [3, 4]]]]}
poly_shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(poly_context)
```

Comment: Scaling is an affine transformation, so you could use [`shapely.affinity.scale()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.affinity.scale).

Comment: affinity.scale can only scale polygon in ratio, I want to scale it up at a fixed scalar.

Comment: To make it a fixed scalar, just make the `xfact` and `yfact` arguments the same value.

Comment: @martineau, you should make this an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your polygon is not convex, the `scale` method may not give you the desired output. For example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import Polygon
from shapely import affinity

vertices = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0.5), (2.5, 2), (0.5, 2.5)]

# Create the polygon
polygon = Polygon(vertices)

scaled_polygon = affinity.scale(polygon, xfact=1.2, yfact=1.2)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [scaled_polygon, polygon]})
gdf.plot(column='geometry')
```

[image]

So, maybe the desired method should be `buffer`instead of `scale`.
Example:

```
buffered_polygon = polygon.buffer(0.2, join_style=2)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [buffered_polygon, polygon]})
gdf.plot(column='geometry')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, One year later I found my new question's answer here!

Comment: Is polygon.buffer provide scaling based on ratio? I want to get second result but I found buffer seems only provide scaling based on fixed number instead of ratio

Comment: No, unfortunately, buffer is for fixed values only. You could try changing the buffer value according to the total width or height of your original shape multiplied by a constant factor..